# Change Environment registry key based on whether installer in user or admin mode

Tags: windows, installation, registry, inno-setup

If the user runs the installer in admin mode, the system path should be modified and if the installer is run in user mode, then the user environment variable need to me modified.

```
[Registry]

; If user installation mode
#define EnvironmentRootKey "HKCU"
#define EnvironmentKey "Environment"
; If admin mode
#define EnvironmentRootKey "HKLM"
#define EnvironmentKey "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

Root: {#EnvironmentRootKey}; Subkey: "{#EnvironmentKey}"; ValueType: expandsz; \
  ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};{app}\bin"; Tasks: addtopath; \
  Check: NeedsAddPath(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin'))
```

I know `HKA` automatically resolves to `HKCU` if the installer is in user mode and `HKLM` in admin mode, but there is no automatic equivalent for `EnvironmentKey`.

Basically something like:

```
#if "HKA" == "HKCU"
#define EnvironmentKey "Environment"
#else
#define EnvironmentKey "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "{code:GetEnvironmentKey}"; ...
```

```pascal
[Code]
function GetEnvironmentKey(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsAdminInstallMode then
    Result := 'System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
  else
    Result := 'Environment';
end;
```

---

Another option is using the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; \
    Subkey: "Environment"; \
    Check: not IsAdminInstallMode; ...

Root: HKLM; \
    Subkey: "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; \
    Check: IsAdminInstallMode; ...
```

*It's more "code", but no `Code`.*